# Find the maximum length of a graph

Tags: java, graph

I need your help to solve a problem. This is part of a coding exercise, that I couldn't solve completely.

Imagine we have the following graph :

[image]

I need to build a class that calculates the maximum length of the path. I don't have a root and have to use each vertex as a starting point.The method has a parameter of maximum number of repeats, so if this 1, we can just pass each edge one time, if it's 2 we can pass a maximum of 2 times each edge.

in this case, if repeats=1, the maximum path should be (B,A,C). It repeats=2, then the maximum path should be (B, A, B, A, C, C).

To solve the problem without repeats, I thought of building an adjacency list and run a DFS to find all the paths in the graph and extract the maximum one. I think this should work for the simpler case.

But I don't know how to do when we can repeat edges. What kind of algorithm can I use to solve this problem. Also can you think of a more efficient approach to this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Surely if each edge can be visited once (and presumably each node can be visted any number), you should get BABCC? BAC isn't even a valid path with the graph you've drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a modified version of depth first search.

In this case you don't only mark a node as **visited** but you add some satellite data to them: **times visited** and when it reaches `repeats` you mark them **visited**.

The modified pseudocode from wikipedia:

```
procedure DFS(G,v):
    increment v.timesVisited
    for all edges e in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
        if edge e.timesVisited < repeats then
            w ← G.adjacentVertex(v,e)
            if vertex w.timesVisited < repeats then
                e.timesVisited++
                recursively call DFS(G,w)
            else
                label e as a back edge
```

I hope it works I did not test the modifications.

Comment: I think you need to reset the number of visits in a node once it has completed traveling in its sub-tree.

Comment: I did implement a version of this and it works as expected. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly,
the solution is similar for both cases.

For the solution with no repeats: You take each node as root ,
and start a DFS on its children.
A valid child of a node is a node that has not ben visited yet.

For the N-repeat problem:
A valid child is a node that has been visited less than N times.
In each visit in the DFS , you need to update the visit counter of that node.
Plus , when you finish exploring the sub-nodes of a specific node, you need to zero its visit counter.

Answer (score 0):

I can see a naïve approach.It's not efficiency but it works.

Two elements :

- A Hashmap with an entry for each edge set to 0
- Fetch the graph using DFS (increment and decrement the hashmap to know your fetching)

As you don't have a root, I think you will have to do this fetching for each node.

Do you need to find all solutions or are you looking for an approaching solution ?

You can't find more explanation on wikipedia about this sort of problem :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem